# How to convert lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree to a tuple in python?

Tags: python

```
from lxml import etree

    elem = etree.parse(xmlfile) 
    transform = etree.XSLT(xsltscript)
    result = transform(elem)
    str(result)//is a csv file
```

result is my **lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree** object. I want to convert that as tuple. How can I do that in python?

I get CSV file as my output. I want to convert that as tuple.

Comment: What is the type of result you're getting, have you tried to loop into result?

Comment: @CSMaverick I get CSV file as my output. I want to convert that as tuple.

Comment: so you want the csv file literally as tuples by rows?

Comment: Updated the answer and let me know if that not helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the result into tuples by rows.

```
import csv
from lxml import etree

elem = etree.parse(xmlfile) 
transform = etree.XSLT(xsltscript)
result = transform(elem)
str(result)//is a csv file

with open(result) as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
print data
```